# Conditional code execution if jQuery AJAX request succeeds/fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

How would I show if no IPv6 or IPv4 address was available with an if/else statement for the following jQuery functions? The request will fail in case no IP address of that type is available.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://v6.ident.me/.json",
    function(json) {
      document.write("Your IPv6 Address: ", json.address);
    }
  );

  $.getJSON("https://v4.ident.me/.json",
    function(json) {
      document.write("Your IPv4 Address: ", json.address);
    }
  );
});
```

I would also like to know the best way to ensure a consistent output order of the addresses.

Comment: You need to do your validation inside the success function of each call. I'm guessing that call returns whether an IP is available or not, so validate with the return you have and change the "output" accordingly.

Comment: Would you mind illustrating what you mean? I'm a bit of a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something depending on if you get an answer at all, or no answer (fail to connect).

Because receiving JSON via AJAX is asynchronous, you cannot use a regular `if/else` statement in this situation. Instead, you should use the [callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that jQuery provides.

To ensure a specific order, you can do two things:

1. execute the callbacks in a given order; or
2. put the data in a specified position on the page.

I will demonstrate the latter option.

```js
$(function() {

  function checkIP(version) {
    $.get('https://ipv' + version + '.myip.info/', 'text')
      .done(function(ip) {
        $('#v' + version).text('IPv' + version + ': ' + ip);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        $('#v' + version).text('IPv' + version + ': not available');
      });
  }

  checkIP(4);
  checkIP(6);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="v4"></p>
<p id="v6"></p>
```

*Because the service used originally in the question went down, this answer uses different URLs.

As a consequence, the data is also plain text instead of JSON. You can look at [older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43570745/revisions/) of this post to see how JSON could be handled.

The idea is the same regardless of which service is used, of course.*

Comment: A little bit magic again, thank you. I changed .text to .html to support some of my inline html code. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has been answered correctly, I'm posting this answer to help explain my comment, hope it helps.

So, I thought the call you were making to get the IP address returned some sort of error if the IP was not found, but I realised that it fails if no IP is found.

In any case an example of what I meant is something like the following:

As an example imagine that the call you are making if an IP is not found instead of failing, it returns `address` as `null`. In that case to check whether you have a correct IP or not you'd have to validate it in the `done()` callback function that you have.

```
$.getJSON("https://v4.ident.me/.json")
    .done(function(json) {
      if(json.address === null) {
        document.write("No IPv4");
      } else {
        document.write("Your IPv4 Address: ", json.address);
      }
    }).fail(function() {
        document.write('Could not determine IP address.');
    });
```

Note that the `fail()` callback function is used for unhandled exceptions, i.e. errors that the server did not cater for. They usually occur when something "unexpected" happens, which is why it is a good idea to still verify the data returned in the `done()` callback function.